# Wordpress advanced custom fields external link text for multiple external links in one post

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using the [ACF](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) plugin on a website. Let's say in a post I want to add multiple external links and I want each link to have a configurable display text instead of the permalink. Doing this for a single external link using ACF isn't hard but I can't figure out how to do it for multiple external links all on the same post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should look at ACF repeater http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/repeater/

its meant to do what you have described. The Repeater field acts as a table of data where you can define the columns (sub fields) and add infinite rows.

```
<?php
```

// check if the repeater field has rows of data
if( have_rows('repeater_field_name') ):

```
// loop through the rows of data
while ( have_rows('repeater_field_name') ) : the_row();

    // display a sub field value
    the_sub_field('sub_field_name');

endwhile;
```

else :

```
// no rows found
```

endif;

?>